# best search in mdb for big data

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have created a dictionary for English to Kurdish and I saved my data in .mdb  access file, my data are more than 78,000 words.
Please can anyone help me to make a quick search?
I'm using this query for search 
"SELECT english FROM table WHERE English LIKE '" +text Searchlight. Text+"%'";

Comment: What's the problem with that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is:

```
SELECT english
FROM table
WHERE English LIKE '" +text Searchlight. Text+"%'"
```

Then I'm a little confused.  Access generally uses `*` as the wildcard for searching rather than `%` (which is the SQL standard).  Because the `LIKE` pattern does not start with a wildcard, many databases will use an index (if available) for this query.  I don't know if MS Access has this optimization.

In any case, you seem to be going down a path where full text search is beneficial.  If so, I think you have the wrong tool for the job.  MS Access doesn't support full text search.  I would suggest that you use a database that does (obvious choices are SQL Server Express, Postgres, and MySQL, all of which are free).  By the way, all three of these do use an index for `LIKE`, when the pattern does not start with a wildcard character.

If you decide to use SQL Server Express, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407337/express-with-advanced-services-cant-create-full-text-index) should be helpful for the installation.

Comment: Gordon Linoff You are right about * and % it was my fault.