# What is the best way for implementing a fast user-interface wildcard text search (MS Access)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have several fields in a table that I want the user to be able to search for using wildcards. What I'm really looking for is a way to do a wildcard search that promotes a fair user experience (e.g. not clunky; decent speed; if not fast, then maybe it processes in the background). I know wildcard searches are frowned upon; and I may even scrap this feature if there's no viable solution. I would like to mention that I'm looking for ideas more than I am looking for specific code.

Here is an example to show what I have tried so far. Consider this hypothetical table with 3 fields that have text (the purpose of this table is irrelevant):

**tableWidget**

```
ID     |     Field1     |     Field2     |     Field3    |
1      | jimmy john     | waldo johnson  | carmen smith  |
2      | francis        | david smith    | NULL          |
3      | yvonne         | harry t.       | mr. waldo     |
4      | dr. waldo, md  | hal            | NULL          |
```

So I want to find all records that have "waldo" in it. My first hunch is to do something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM tableWidget
WHERE ID IN
(
  SELECT ID FROM tableWidget WHERE
  Field1 LIKE '*waldo*' OR
  Field2 LIKE '*waldo*' OR
  Field3 LIKE '*waldo*'
)
```

The problem here is that with the number of records I'm running, it is extremely slow. The second attempt I did was something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM tableWidget
WHERE ID IN
(
  SELECT ID FROM tableWidget 
  WHERE  Field1 & Field2 & Field3 LIKE '*waldo*'
)
```

This is still slow. The third way I tried this was to have a Form_Timer event that cycles through tableWidget and does a VBA comparison. My form's recordset was something like this:

```
SELECT * FORM tableWidget
WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM tempTable)
```

The snippet of code to append to the tape looked something like this"

```
With rsTableWidget
  If Searching=True AND NOT .EOF Then

    If INSTR(.Fields("Field1") & .Fields("Field2") & ".Fields("Field3"), "waldo") > 0 Then
      rsTempTable.AddNew
      rsTempTable.Fields("ID")=.Fields("ID")
      rsTempTable.Update
      mySubForm.Requery
    End If

    rsTableWidget.MoveNext

  Else

    Searching=False
    rsTableWidget.Close: rsTempTable.Close

  End If
End With
```

The good thing about this was that it would update in the background. The bad thing about this was that every iteration of Form_Timer, it would flicker. And when it found a record, the mySubForm.requery method would reset the form--not very user friendly.

Other methods I've considered was using VBA code to regularly parse through every word (delimited by spaces) and create a search table:

**tableSearchTerm**:

```
ID    |    searchTerm
1     |    jimmy
1     |    john
1     |    waldo
1     |    johnson
1     |    carmen
1     |    smith
2     |    francis
2     |    david
2     |    smith
etc...
```

I haven't tried this yet, but I suppose the good thing would be that I could index the searchTerm. And I wouldn't have to use wildcards anymore because all the terms are associated with the ID. The bad thing is that this table will get huge quick!

Is there a better method?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using wildcards - it's required in your case so there's any alternatives. If you're having to do it on three text fields with an OR, there's not going to be much you can do speed-wise. Personally I don't see any benefit in using a Timer. You can try indexing the three fields - but with using wildcards on both sides of your seacrh term, I'm not sure if that will help at all.

Comment: P.S. What is your number of records, and what is "extremely slow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks over-complicated, why don't you use this?

```
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM tableWidget
WHERE 
  Field1 LIKE '*waldo*' OR
  Field2 LIKE '*waldo*' OR
  Field3 LIKE '*waldo*'
```

But yes, a full text search with wildcards at the **beginning** of the search terms, will be slow, because no index can be used.

You may want to look at migrating to a server database as backend, that has a Full-Text Search capability. E.g. [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

This Q&A says it also works with the Express edition: [Express with Advanced Services, can't create Full Text Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407337/express-with-advanced-services-cant-create-full-text-index)

If that is not an option, I suggest to let the user choose to

- search beginnings of fields (`Field1 LIKE 'waldo*'`), which will be much faster if you index the fields, or
- do the slow full text search.

It depends on your data. For names e.g., the first option is almost always sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I decided to create VBA code to create a searchQuery and a searchTable (which has indexed search terms). The code syncs them up to make sure they are the same always. The initial build was long, but the code to update it was quick. And I used your advice about only using asterisk wildcard at the end. It was dramatically faster. So in the end it was a combination of using indexed fields and proper wildcard usage. Thanks.