# Full text search with concatenating tables in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just starting out with full text searching and I've always used wildcards in the past. Here's a query I have:

```
SELECT rID, claimID+counter FROM claims WHERE claimID+counter LIKE '%ba%' AND (status='submitted' OR status='closed')
```

I'm trying to convert this to contains but I get an error saying that the column doesn't exist.

```
SELECT rID, claimID+counter FROM claims WHERE contains(claimID+counter,'ba') AND (status='submitted' OR status='closed')
```

I  tried the above and no go. How do i fix this?

Comment: is there any column called claimId+counter?

Comment: there is not. There is a claimID and counter column. When i do a wildcard search of claimID+counter I don't have any issues. Only happens when I use contains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT rID, claimID+counter FROM claims WHERE contains((claimID,counter),'ba') AND (status='submitted' OR status='closed')
```

If you get error running above script like

```
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'claims' because it is not full-text indexed.
```

Then make sure  you have `full-text search feature installed`.
Follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it) for more detail

Comment: did you try your statement yourself?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri yes i got error and hence i posted the required solution . I always post working solutions

Comment: I think author wants to combine those columns and search in combined result. claimID+counter LIKE '%ba%'. so claim may be b, counter may be a. and  claimID+counter = 'ba'. contains((claimID,counter),'ba') is different..

Comment: Hey Giorgi... you are exactly right. How do i pull this off?

Comment: @Damien, I am not sure if SQL Server supports such functionality