# How to search a word inside a string where word is in a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server table with two columns `Keyword` and `Emotion`.

I want to search a word (which is specified in column `Keyword`) inside a string which contains a sentence.. for eg:- How are you

I want to execute two queries:

1. I want to search if the string contains "how" (`how` is specified in `Keyword` column)..
2. If the string contains `how`, I want to display the corresponding value stored in the `Emotion` column of the table

This is my sample code (which can be completely wrong :p):-

```
public partial class message : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AnonymiousSocialNetworkConnectionString"].ToString();

    protected void btnsend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        string value = txtmsg.Text;
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select emotion from messageanalysis where keyword CONTAINS'",con);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while(myReader.Read())
        {
            lblStatus.Text = myReader["emotion"].ToString();// **this label should Display corresponding value stored in Emotion(column)**//
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see why you need two queries, the one you have should be sufficient.

Comment: I meant to say I want two operations to be performed which is searching of a word & getting the corresponding value

Comment: Well, thats what that semi  sql does.... So.. Im not getting your question or problem.

Comment: the code i provided doesnt work it gives sql exceptions.. So i want to fix this code

Comment: Ok, so, whats the errors whats the full sql generated?

Comment: $exception {"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONTAINS'."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Comment: Well, you dont add the closing quote which wont help.  Keyword is possibly reserved...

Comment: Ps, of you looked at the string you submitted part of that would have been obvious

Comment: Does my code syntax and logic seems Right to you? @BugFinder

Comment: Logic is fine. Syntax of sql may suffer of keyword is reserved, but if you follow that through.. Hence my confusion, the principal was ok. You didnt post what was wrong.  We arent mind readers

Comment: Can you fix that errors? m nt getting you :(  Am i supposed to use value.contains() method?

Comment: Why dont you read the sql syntax of contains.......

Comment: i did but it doesnt mention how can i use a local variable in c#  like "value" in a sql Statement

Comment: The same way you would insert it into any other string in c#

Answer (score 0):

You just need only one SQL command and that should be like below -

```
string searchParam = "hello";                
SqlCommand    myCommand = new SqlCommand("select emotion from messageanalysis where CONTAINS(keyword,@SearchParam)",con);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SearchParam", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = searchParam,;
```

CONTAINS may not work if full-text feature is not enabled on server. Please check this link for more details - [Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it)

If you do not want to enable this feature then use LIKE -

```
SqlCommand    myCommand = new SqlCommand("select emotion from messageanalysis where keyword like @SearchParam)",con);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SearchParam", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "%" + searchParam + "%";
```

Comment: i dont want to mention 'how' next to keyword as you have shown.. just a direct link to the column which contains hundreds of words one of which can be 'how'

Comment: it is giving me this error--->    Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'messageanalysis' because it is not full-text indexed.

Comment: I am not sure if i could understand your question, i have edited my answer to use parameterised query, hope that should work for you.

Comment: check this out for the error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it

Comment: Both methods doesnt work.. it gives must declare scalar variable @searchparam

Comment: by mistake I have used `cmd` instead of `myCommand` to add a parameter, edited my answer, try now..

Comment: what will this command do exactly..? m unable to understand :( I have enabled full text search to use contains and i have set the data type of table columns as Text.. so i should change it to System.Data.SqlDbType.Text ? and should i remove the execute reader from my program?

Comment: Correct you should use Text datatype and don't remove ExecuteReader, are you getting any exception now?

Comment: are you able to run this command using SQL management studio `select emotion from messageanalysis where CONTAINS(keyword,'how')` ?