# How do I look for part of a string in a field and if it exists replace it with another field?

Tags: t-sql

I'm building a case in my query where if a field is either blank or has the substring 'Name Not Found' then the field in question should be replaced with the value of another field.

This is what I have so far:
    `CASE WHEN [Salesperson1 Name] = '' THEN [Salesperson Name (Primary)]`
    `WHEN CONTAINS([Salesperson1 Name], 'Name Not Found') THEN [Salesperson Name (Primary)]`
    `ELSE [Salesperson1 Name]`
    `END,`

but when I run the query I get this message:
    `Msg 7601, Level 16, State 2, Line 19`
    `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'staging_leads_rr' because it is not full-text indexed.`

How could I get this done? What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure what the error message means, because I'm new to writing stuff in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Contains** function relates to the Full-Text search functionality of SQL Server which is more suited for large scale text processing. See reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

In order to do this simply you should use something more like the charindex function, which returns a positive value relating to the first character position of the search string if the string is indeed found and 0 if not : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Then your query would look more like this;

```
CASE WHEN [Salesperson1 Name] = '' THEN [Salesperson Name (Primary)]
WHEN CHARINDEX( 'Name Not Found', [Salesperson1 Name]) > 0 THEN [Salesperson Name (Primary)]
ELSE [Salesperson1 Name]
END,
```

Comment: Would this lead to false positives if a sales person's name started with 'N'?

Comment: The whole string must be matched otherwise 0 is returned. I have just verified this using [SELECT CHARINDEX( 'Name Not Found', 'NOT the string we are looking for')] which returned 0. So this would only be an issue if the string 'Name Not Found' appeared somewhere within the sales persons name (which seems unlikely :) )

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the call to `CONTAINS` with the `LIKE` operator:

```
CASE WHEN [Salesperson1 Name] = ''
     THEN [Salesperson Name (Primary)]
     WHEN [Salesperson1 Name] LIKE '%Name Not Found%'
     THEN [Salesperson Name (Primary)]
ELSE [Salesperson1 Name]
END
```

If you really want to use `CONTAINS` then you will have to create a full text index on the `[Salesperson1 Name]` column, q.v. [this helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it).