# Orbeon Summary Page Search Issue

Tags: sql, xpath, orbeon, exist-db

I'm getting following error while searching in Summary Page

[image]

Confusing thing is if I expand “Show search options”  & Search it works perfectly fine.

What might be the issue?

For back-end we are using MS SQL

Comment: Which version of Orbeon Forms are you using? Can you check [`orbeon.log`](http://doc.orbeon.com/installation/#logging-configuration) and see if any detailed error is reported?

Comment: We are using 4.8.2, Yes will check that once & let you know further

Comment: As a side note, a different SQL query is used when you do a search with the single text field ("free text search") vs. when you  do so with the field-specific fields you get when opening the "Show search options", which can explain why you get an error in one case and not in the other. You'll let us know what you find in the `orbeon.log`.

Comment: Hi Avernet, will check the logs & get back you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Avernet, Log says "Connection Reset"

Comment: Even after restarting Tomcat server, its still giving same error.

Comment: Hi Pavan, the "Connection Reset" in the logs is typically nothing to be worried about. Are you always getting this error doing a search, or is it only happening some times? Also, could you try stopping the server, deleting the `orbeon.log`, restarting the server, reproducing the problem, pasting the content of the log in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), and linking to it here?

Comment: Hi Avernet, 
I'm always getting the error. 
We restarted the tomcat once but couldn't delete orbeon.log. 
Should check by deleting orbeon.log.

Comment: Hi Avernet, I followed as you said but the issue still persist & there is no error in orbeon.log. 
Please help

Comment: Can you add [more logging](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/xforms-logging.html), and then send us (privately if you want) the orbeon.log?

Comment: Hi Erik & Alex, I have updated the logs on Gist
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/033c12c0f521a4ad686c4241d715397e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Erik's answer, I followed these steps & its working.

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON orbeon_form_data 

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG orbeon_fulltext_catalog_new AS DEFAULT;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX orbeon_from_data_pk_new ON orbeon_form_data (id);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON orbeon_form_data (xml) KEY INDEX orbeon_from_data_pk_new;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error I see is:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view because it is not full-text indexed"

This usually indicates that you don't have the full-text feature installed. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003240/cannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate-on-table-or-indexed-view-because-it).

It could also be because you haven't created the indexes from the [DDL files](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/36593f688ec312a609e943d1490c6f950e3ef1a0/form-runner/src/main/resources/apps/fr/persistence/relational/ddl/sqlserver-2016_2.sql) (link and SQL below as of Orbeon Forms 2016.2):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG orbeon_fulltext_catalog AS DEFAULT;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX orbeon_from_data_pk ON orbeon_form_data (id);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON orbeon_form_data (xml) KEY INDEX orbeon_from_data_pk;
```

Comment: Hi Erik, This worked! Thanks a lot. 
Index was already present for orbeon_form_data, so I had to Drop Index & Recreate.